# Analyse day-time of a date-time variable

Tags: r, lubridate

This is how I solved the problem:

```
datestimes <- c("2014-01-01 23:03:00", "2014-01-02 00:35:00", "2014-01-02 00:51:00") # There is a change in date. 
# Is there any lubridate command for the following step?    
time <- as.POSIXct(strftime(datetimes, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"), format = "%H:%M:%S") 
time  
[1] "2016-05-13 23:03:00 CEST" "2016-05-13 00:35:00 CEST" "2016-05-13 00:51:00 CEST"
```

Is there a reason that there is no such functionality in lubridate? 
As I said - I am only interested in the time part - not the date.

`lubridate::hms` gives periods:

```
ltime <- lubridate::hms(strftime(datetimes, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"))  
ltime  
[1] "23H 3M 0S" "35M 0S"    "51M 0S"  
class(ltime)  
[1] "Period"  
attr(,"package")  
[1] "lubridate"
```

Comment: Can you please describe your problem more clearly? A time without a date is not well defined, since there are inconveniences such as DST and even the occasional leap second.

Comment: `lubridate` doesn't have a class for times without dates (aside from periods, which are a little different, though you could make work). You might check out `chron`.

Comment: Well lubridate can extract hour, minutes, seconds. Also you can use regex to get the time component.

Comment: I guess you can literally do the same thing with `ymd_hms(paste(today(), format(ymd_hms(datetimes), '%T')))`...but I'm not sure it's a very good approach.

Comment: @Roland: Assume `datetimes` are instants, where people where counted in the cinema building. Now you want to analyse, when people go to the cinema, depending on day time. Do you have a better idea than alistaire? @alistaire: Your approach seems to do exactly what I need - and it is precise as it tells you that you overwrite the date by `today`.

Comment: @Chirayu Chamoli: parse_date_time(datestimes, "%H:%M:%S") fails. chron::times(datestimes) also fails. Both are format issues.

Comment: @Christoph: Not that, I meant minute(datestimes),hour(datestimes),second(datestimes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to alistair: `ymd_hms(paste(today(), format(ymd_hms(datetimes), '%T')))` will be my choice. This can be nicely combined with `hist` or `ggplot2` (See above).

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
library(lubridate)
datetimes <- c("2014-01-01 23:03:00", "2014-01-02 00:35:00", "2014-01-02 00:51:00") 
dataset <- data.frame(
  time = as.POSIXct(strftime(datetimes, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"), format = "%H:%M:%S") 
)
dataset$delta <- dataset$time - floor_date(dataset$time, unit = "day")
dataset$relative <- as.POSIXct("2001-01-01 0:0:0") + minutes(dataset$delta)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = relative)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3600) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hour", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

Comment: The advantage of alistaire's method is, that you have hours and minutes (and seconds) available. Thus you can have a simple and nice histogram of the form `brks <- trunc(range(time), "hours")` + 
`hist(time, breaks = seq(brks[1], brks[2] + 3600, by = "15 min"), freq = T)`. Plots with 1 hour or 30 minutes resolution are also easily accessible.

Comment: I've used my answer. `ggplot2` has lots of options to format datetime classes.

Comment: Everything but the line `+ scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hour", date_labels = "%H:%M")` works: `Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "datetime", identity, breaks = breaks,  : unused arguments (date_breaks = "3 hour", date_labels = "%H:%M")` I just took your code.

Comment: It works on my machine with R 3.3.0, ggplot2 2.1.0, scales 0.4.0, lubridate 1.5.6. Check if you have the latest versions of the packages.

Comment: yep:-) +1 for pointing me to ggplot2 and how it works here. I still think you use the trick to overwrite the date - and here alistaire's way is the most clear one for me.